# Swapped parameters for a grails URL mapping

Tags: rest, grails

I am using grails 3 to model hierarchical structures in a database to controllers. I have the following URL mapping:

```
group("/api") {
            "/events"(resources: 'event') {
                get "/attendees"(controller: 'eventAttendee', action: 'index')
                delete "/attendees/$id"(controller:'eventAttendee', action: 'delete')
                post "/attendees"(controller:'eventAttendee', action: 'save')
            }
            "/attendees"(resources: 'attendee')
        }
```

If I `GET` `/api/events/1/attendees` I see that the `params` contain an `eventId` field, which correctly displays 1. However, if I `DELETE`  `/api/events/1/attendess/2`I get params where `eventId => 2` and `Id => 1` (the parameters are swapped). This is causing me some problems, does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: Regarding the controllers: This is the relevant part of the source, I don't think there's anything suspicious there:

```
class EventController extends RestfulController {

    EventController() {
        super(Event)
    }
}

class EventAttendeeController {
  def delete() {
    print "${params.eventId}"
    print "${params.Id}"
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: please post the contents from UrlMappings.groovy

Comment: The code block on display is showing the relevant part of `UrlMappings.groovy`

Comment: Oh! I am sorry. I meant to say controller but ended up typing UrlMappings.

Answer (score 1):

Although its old question, Trying this might help someone,

```
group("/api") {
            "/events"(resources: 'event') {
               "/attendees"(resources: 'attendee')
            }
        }
```